# pig script to replace \ with - in date function

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to write a pig script which has date in the format 04/15/2016. I want to convert it to `04-15-2016`. I am getting when I do the below:

```
x=REPLACE(date,'\','-');
dump x;
```

I want to know the correct way of writing this.

Thanks,
stacky

Answer (score 0):

Cast the field as chararray in [REPLACE](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#replace).

```
REPLACE(string, 'oldChar', 'newChar');

X = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE((chararray)date,'/','-');
dump X;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
X = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(date,'/','-');
DUMP X;
```